# What are the keywords that give you a "green light" for punching?

Tags: battery

I read [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-punching-someone-an-arrestable-offence-but-saying-something-hurtful-to-their-face-is-not) that the First Amendment allows you to say whatever you want to someone without the government interfering, so long as your words do not pose an imminent threat of harm to another (and a couple other exceptions).

So what are those keywords that give you a "green light" for punching ?

Can punching be justified ? Let's say somebody says horrible things about my wife, does that give me a "green light" to punch ? What is the "punching power" limit ?  Is "slap in the face" okay ? LOL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8673/when-punching-can-be-legal)

Comment: Will Smith sends his regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: [Similar Q&A here](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/8594/10).

The only legal justifications for [battery](/questions/tagged/battery) that I am aware of are:

1. Defense (especially [self-defense](/questions/tagged/self-defense))
2. To prevent a more serious felony
3. To effect a lawful [arrest](/questions/tagged/arrest)

Although "fighting words" are not protected speech, AFAIK they do not *justify* a violent act (even though they are defined as words likely to *provoke* one).  But **words constituting [assault](/questions/tagged/assault)** – i.e., creating a reasonable apprehension of an imminent threat that *justifies* the use of force, as enumerated above – *can*.

Answer (score 1):

There are no words that "green light" a punch.

Comment: Not even "would you like a boxing match"?

Comment: So how are boxing matches legally held?